# 0xD1 on megasas2.sys with LSI-9240-8i during data transfer

Tags: raid10, lsi, power-supply-unit

I have an older Intel S3210SHLX motherboard with a HighPoint 2310 RAID card, running four 500GB drives in a RAID5 array. The OS is WHS2011, and everything is fine, except that I'm running out of room.

My solution is four 4TB drives run through an LSI 9240-8i, purchased off of eBay. The drives are in a RAID10 configuration, and have successfully been slow initialized and GPT formatted. The power supply is a Corsair Gold AX750, which should have plenty of headroom. (Yes, I acknowledge that I should have gone with 2TB drives, which could have been connected directly into the motherboard, and used the Intel 9CHR chip to manage.)

The system runs fine, and has initialized and formatted the drives. There are no errors cropping up from the new hardware.

However, when I am transferring data to the new array, it consistently moves between 20 and 30GB of data, then blue-screens with a 0xD1 (Driver IRQL) error, pointing at the megasas2.sys.

I've run diagnostics on it through megacli, with a 0x00 exit code (OK). The drives don't show any SMART errors.

I've considered rebuilding the system with a Server 2008 r2 license I have handy, since WHS2011 was never 'certified' with the LSI cards, but that seems excessive.

Any thoughts or other approaches? Am I overtaxing my old (but powerful) power supply? Do I have a bad card?